# Nginx conflicting server name in server block configuration

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

After getting certbot certificates i get the following error when doing nginx -t :

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "naos-soultrap.online" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.naos-soultrap.online" on 0.0.0.0:80,ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Here is my server block configuration :

```
server {

    server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;

    root /home/pierre/public/naossoultrap;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/escapingthematrix.online/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/escapingthematrix.online/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.naos-soultrap.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = naos-soultrap.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;
     return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = naos-soultrap.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: The copy paste for code did not work correctly , i chose the code bracket and paste my config in it but it doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warning literally tell you what is wrong with the config:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "naos-soultrap.online" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.naos-soultrap.online" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

Two of your server configurations (which you have three of in total) have conflicting names.

The first server block is for https/443:

```
server {

    server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;
    root /home/pierre/public/naossoultrap;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/escapingthematrix.online/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/escapingthematrix.online/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

After that you have two http/80 server blocks with identical server names and if we look close enough we can notice that the second http/80 server block here is redundant and in fact doesn't add any new configuration on top of the first server http/80 block. I would assume you can safely remove it.

```
server { 
    if ($host = www.naos-soultrap.online) { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = naos-soultrap.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
} 

server { 
    if ($host = naos-soultrap.online) { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name naos-soultrap.online www.naos-soultrap.online;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the issue. Regards Peter